# Create parent directories when using shell redirect

Tags: shell, zsh, configuration, io-redirection

In Zsh, the following fails:

```
$ echo hi > /tmp/this/path/does/not/exist/out.txt
zsh: no such file or directory: /tmp/this/path/does/not/exist/out.txt
```

Obviously the problem is that `>` cannot create missing parent directories. I find this behavior very annoying, it should just create the dirs. How can I accomplish this?

With the likes of `cp` and `mkdir` it is possible to just alias the `--parents` option. However `>` cannot be aliased, as it is not a command. What can I do?

Ideally I would like to accomplish this in zsh, but I will accept "use a different shell" as an answer.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that. If you really want to store output in that directory you should make sure it exists.

Comment: There is a strong argument that it should *not* create the directory: every typo would be able to create some directory tree that you do not know about. Also, this would be asymmetric with `<`: you would not want to create a directory branch that cannot have the actual file present. The `--parents` options are additional actions for specific cases: having a plain redirection always do this would be chaotic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always create a:

```
create() { mkdir -p -- $1:h && cat > $1; }
```

And use:

```
echo something | create path/to/some/file
```

Or even:

```
create() {
  local dest
  for dest do
    mkdir -p -- $dest:h || return
  done
  cat > "$@"
}
```

To be able do do:

```
echo hi | create some/file some/other/file
```

---

Another approach:

```
makeparents() {
  mkdir -p -- $1:h
  print -r -- $1
}
```

And:

```
echo hi > "$(makeparents path/to/some/file)"
```

(won't work for file names that end in newline characters)

You could also do it using zsh's dynamic named directory expansion:

```
redir-parent() {
  [[ $1 = n ]] && [[ $2 = p:* ]] || return
  local file=${2#p:}
  mkdir -p -- $file:h
  reply=($file)
}

zsh_directory_name_functions+=(redir-parent)
```

And then:

```
echo something > ~[p:path/to/some/file]
```

Where `path/to/some` would be created as part of the expansion.

---

In any case, in all of those, when path directory components are created, they will have default permissions as affected by the current umask.

In the `cmd | create path/to/file` version, `cmd` will be run even if `/path/to` can't be created or `path/to/file` can't be opened (and could end up being killed with a SIGPIPE).

In the other ones, the failed redirection will cancel the running of `cmd`. They also have the advantage of preserving `cmd`'s exit status.

If not all directory components can be created or if the file can't be opened for writing, you could end up with *some* directories having been created even if the redirection itself failed. You may then want to do some manual cleanup.